# How to catch syntax node for identifier in LINQ expression group ... into <identifier>

Tags: c#, linq, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to process all identifiers in code with my custom code analyzer.
I catched all of these except an identifier **`y`** in such expression:

```
var z = from x in new int[] { }
        group x by x into y
        select new { };
```

There is minimal analyzer source code example:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class IdentifierAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor("Id", "", "", "Naming", DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, true, null);
    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);
    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.Analyze | GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKinds);
    }

    private static readonly SyntaxKind[] SyntaxKinds = new[] {
                                                           SyntaxKind.JoinIntoClause,
                                                           //TODO: LINQ group...into <identifier>
                                                       };

    private static void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Node)
        {
            case JoinIntoClauseSyntax joinIntoClause:
                if (IsNotValid(joinIntoClause.Identifier.Text))
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, joinIntoClause.Identifier.GetLocation(), joinIntoClause.Identifier.Text));
                break;
            //TODO: LINQ group...into <identifier>
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static bool IsNotValid(string text)
    {            
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (context.Node)
        {
            case JoinIntoClauseSyntax joinIntoClause:
                if (IsNotValid(joinIntoClause.Identifier.Text))
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, joinIntoClause.Identifier.GetLocation(), joinIntoClause.Identifier.Text));
                break;
            case QueryContinuationSyntax continuationSyntax:
                if (IsNotValid(continuationSyntax.Identifier.Text))
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, continuationSyntax.Identifier.GetLocation(), continuationSyntax.Identifier.Text));
                break;
        }
```